# Is there an equivalent EE term for "homeostasis"?

Tags: reference

In biology, [homeostasis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeostasis) is the state of steady internal physical and chemical conditions maintained by living systems.

Is there an equivalent term for a circuit or electronic device?  So that would be constant supply voltage, surrounding EMI field, ambient illumination, temperature etc., etc.

Answer (score 2):

Quiescent point, or bias point is the name for the DC conditions eg in an amplifier with no signal. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biasing for more details.

There is also the concept of stability in control systems which might be what you are looking for, in terms of returning smoothly to the desired point without oscillation.

Comment: Martin is correct. But I will add also that the data sheets sometime refer to the steady state operation of the device as the "quiescent operation" especially when there are capacitor that need to be charged to a constant DC for proper operation of the circuit.

Answer (score 1):

You might just be looking for the engineering term ["steady state"](https://ultimateelectronicsbook.com/steady-state-transient/) (in contrast to "transient" behavior), which is a phrase that can refer to something as simple and specific as:

$$\frac {d} {dt} = 0$$

but can also refer to something much more complicated, such as active feedback maintaining a regulated voltage level through a nonlinear PWM switching power supply.

Answer (score 0):

We generally just call it "equilibrium" — processes in balance that keep certain parameters constant.

Comment: And, like homeostasis, we apply the term "equalibrium" to a system that has some passive part whose resting state **isn't** the system equalibrium, that's being forced to that equalibrium by an active control system.  Think body temperature -- we stay right around 37C because active regulation makes it happen, where our "natural" temperature may range above or below that, depending on the immediate environment and what we're doing.